# drag drop to desktop in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, drag-and-drop, desktop, nsview

I am trying to do an application in objective-c able to drag&drop files from the application to the desktop or finder.
I have the functionality to allow the drag done but I cant find any tutorial to drop the file. 
Could someone help me on this?
Thanks and regards

Comment: I found the answer by myself. 
I was using the wrong method. I started to use: 
**dragFile:fromRect:slideBack:event:**
And it works perfectly